# Check on TEST mode during runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My web application writes some kind of log during runtime.
I don't want to write this log when running my test suite using cucumber.

So, how can I check my current runtime environment (TEST, DEV or PROD)?

I'm looking for the C equivalent to i.e. :


    `#ifdef DEBUG

       // just run in debug mode

    #endif`

Thank you very much for helping me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the if condition:

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "test"
    # Insert Code Here
end
```

(replace 'test' with 'development' or 'production' as needed)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.
Thank you!

Comment: `Rails.env` is the preferred way to do this now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
Rails.env.test?
Rails.env.development?
Rails.env.production?
```

This will return true or false according to the runtime environment